# Detect strings having odd number of 0s and 1s

Tags: regex

I need to construct a regular expression using language {0,1}

The regular expression should accept odd number of 0's and odd number of 1's

Comment: So any order and any amount of 0s and 1s, so long as the amount of 0s and the amount of 1s are both odd?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Yes no order is required. There can be any number of 0s and 1s as long as their total count remains odd.

Comment: regular expressions cannot count

Comment: What language or environment? Why regex?

Comment: You cannot do that in Regular Expression (at least under its strict definition)

Comment: @akonsu This problem doesn't require counting, but tracking parity (which is finite).

Comment: Why all the down votes? It may not be possible in regex, but it's a well-formed, good question.

Comment: @HerringtonDarkholme Disagree. Can you construct a regex in the language `{0,1}` that accepts an odd number of zeroes? Same principle.

Answer (score 4):

The whole regex:

```
^((00|11)*(10|01)(00|11)*(10|01)(00|11)*|(00|11))*(10|01)((00|11)*(10|01)(00|11)*(10|01)(00|11)*|(00|11))*$
```

A way of conceptualizing it:

```
x = (00|11)
y = (10|01)
z = x*yx*yx*

^(z|x)*y(z|x)*$
```

Because we are thinking about parity, and not counting, this can be done in regex. The pattern `x` does not effect parity, while the pattern `y` switches parity. The pattern `z` looks for matching `y` (net effect of zero on parity), ignoring intervening `x`. Then you just need one `y`.

Perhaps a shorter regex, using `y` to match the last switch of parity, may be:

```
^(z|x)*yx*$
^(x*yx*yx*|x)*yx*
```

Which is:

```
^((00|11)*(10|01)(00|11)*(10|01)(00|11)*|(00|11))*(10|01)(00|11)*$
```

This has not been tested extensively, but I believe it works.

Comment: +1 Both regex verified correct on all valid inputs up to 6 characters, and most invalid inputs up to 7 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you got such complicated answers. This regex will work for you:

```
var re = /^(?!(([^0]*0){2})*[^0]*$)(?!(([^1]*1){2})*[^1]*$)[01]+$/

re.test('010'); // false
re.test('011'); // false 
re.test('01'); // true
re.test('10'); // true
re.test('001101'); // true
re.test('00'); // false
re.test('11'); // false
```

It does its job by using a negative lookahead to make sure there are odd # of 0s to follow and off # of 1s to follow in a string consisting only 0 OR 1

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/hvIkx2

Comment: +1 Verified correct on all valid inputs up to 6 characters, and most invalid inputs up to 7 characters.

Answer (score 0):

However, you can really do this in extended regular expression.

This regular expression support iinfinite `0|1`s string.

```
/(?!^(?:0|10*1)*$)(?!^(?:1|01*0)*$)^[01]+$/
```

The free spacing mode.

```
/
    (?!              # negative lookahead enables checking both 1 or 0
        ^            # match the whole string
        (?:          # no matching group for efficiency and readability
            0|10*1   # 0 or a pair of  1
        )*           # arbitrary `0`s or double `1`s
        $
    )                # end of the lookahead
    (?!              # negative lookahead enables checking both 1 or 0
        ^            # match the whole string
        (?:          # no matching group for efficiency and readability
            1|01*0   # 1 or a pair of  0
        )*           # arbitrary `1`s or double `0`s
        $
    )                # end of the lookahead
    ^[01]+$
/
```

The main point here is:

1. even number of `0|1` can be matched like `/(01*0)*/`
2. zero-width assertion can check string multiple times

Test

```
  function makeStr(n) {
    if (n <= 1) { return ['0', '1'];}
    return makeStr(n-1).reduce(function(acc, ele){
      acc.push('0' + ele);
      acc.push('1' + ele);
      return acc;
    }, [])
  }
  function countOdd(str, char) {
    if (char === 0) {
      return str.replace(/[^0]/g, '').length%2 !== 0;
    } else {
      return str.replace(/[^1]/g, '').length%2 !== 0;
    }
  }
  function valid(str) {
    return countOdd(str, 0) && countOdd(str, 1);
  }

  var reg = /(?!^(?:0|10*1)*$)(?!^(?:1|01*0)*$)^[01]+$/

  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    makeStr(i).forEach(function(e) {
      if (reg.test(e) !== valid(e)) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
  }
```

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/2MZxf/

Online demo: http://ysmood.github.io/regex-builder/

Code:
N4IgpgHgDiBcIAoD8BCAes2AGAPgRiwCo8BKQgEhOXUzxyz0KzMrQG0GBdAanJABoQAMwA2AQwDmAZzggJAWwEgALhGWyGWLAB0AdloZ7NDPEeNHTuvXhs6r+g5b16QAXyAAAA==

Done :)

Comment: Wait for my explanation, it really requires some time

Comment: "even number of `0|1` can be matched like `/(01*0)*/`" - No; for example, `001001` will not be matched.

Comment: -1; this regex fails to match [`0100`, `000100`, `010000`, `011100`], and incorrectly matches [`10010`, `1000010`, `1001000`, `1001110`].

Comment: @Phrogz valid test case. However, the problem of this regex is not `/(01*0)*/`. The problem lies in the position of `(01|10)`. It can appear after odd number of `0|1`