# How to construct regular expression to balance characters in a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have come across regular expressions for different problems but I could not find out regex s to balance characters in a string.

I came across a problem, to find if a string is balanced.
ex: `aabbccdd` is a balanced one, as a characters are repeated in even numbers
but `aabbccddd` is not a balanced one since `ddd` is repeated in odd number mode. This is applicable for all characters give an input not to specific `a,b,c and d`. If i give input as `12344321` or `123454321`, it should return balanced and unbalanced result respectively.

How to find the balance using regex. What type of regular expression we should use to find if the string is balanced?

```
Edit:
```

I tried to find solution using regex only as the problem demands answer in regex pattern. I would implemented using any other solution if regex was not mentioned explicitly

Comment: why do you need regex for that?

Comment: I never liked java, but after reading all the answers and comments - I know - I'm never switching to Java. In python this problem is about 2-5 lines of code without regex and specific libraries ... still cannot believe you can't count characters in string in java ... actually here is SO answer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string , now only compare those counts for each char in string ... it's actually 1-liner as expected

Comment: @Drako Keep in mind the OP asked for a solution based on RegExps (I actually suspect that to be an exam trick question). Regarding Java, it has undergone a few developments recently, and then there are Groovy and Kotlin, which definitely steal Java the show by adding all the syntactic sugar which Python is offering since ages.

Comment: @classstacker You might be right about this being assignment, because I get here for regex tag and find out that no regex is needed even if it would be possible to write it, in python not using lambdas that would shorten it even more, working example have 3-4 lines :) I believe with just few lines more can do the same in Java :) so really must be school question for regex torturing :)

Comment: @classstacker it's perfect task for checking if the student knows how to convert from DFA or NFA to regex. For me DFA would be enough if convertion algorithm provided.

Comment: Sorry, as you can see from my other comments, I thought "balanced" were defined by either repeating the same character seceral times in a row or having a symmetrical character string. This would involve counting.

Comment: @xenteros Yes, once you provide a precise definition of "balanced" -- for me, there's really nothing "balanced" about "13253152", and why would good examples suggest a regularity which is not supposed to be chacked for... anyhow. Nice discussion. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it with regex. Why do you need to use them?
I tried this: it works and it's pretty simple

```
static boolean isBalanced(String str) {
    ArrayList<Character> odds = new ArrayList<>(); //Will contain the characters read until now an odd number of times
    for (char x : str.toCharArray()) { //Reads each char of the string
        if (odds.contains(x)) { //If x was in the arraylist we found x an even number of times so let's remove it
            odds.remove(odds.indexOf(x));
        }
        else {
            odds.add(x);
        }
    }
    return odds.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: I tried my code with all four OP examples and it returns the right value. 12344321 returns true and 123454321 returns false.

Comment: Sorry, as you can see from my other comments, I thought "balanced" were defined by either repeating the same character seceral times in a row or having a symmetrical character string.

Comment: I tried to find solution using regex only as the problem demands answer in regex pattern. I would used any other solution if regex was not mentioned explicitly

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression for this problem exists, but doesn't speed up anythings and will be totally messy. It's easier to prepare NFA, and then switch to REGEX. Still, it's not proper tool.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = args[0];
    int[] counter = new int[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        counter[s.charAt(i)]++;
    }
    if (validate(counter)) {
        System.out.println("valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
}

public static boolean validate(int[] tab) {
    for (int i : tab) {
        if (i%2 == 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Edit:** *for pointing the regex existance*

Reference for a finite automate for just two characters. Start on the very left, win with double circle. Each state named by the set of characters that have odd count so far.

[image]

Comment: @classstacker it is easier to understand for `L={0,1}`. It's well explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/19615508/4723795

Comment: @classstacker regular expressions are izomorfic to NFA, and the nfa would just read char by char and for each char it would have 2 states - even and odd. It would just switch.

Comment: @classstacker please check the DFA attached to the answer. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions describes the convertion

Comment: Sorry, as you can see from my other comments, I thought "balanced" were defined by either repeating the same character seceral times in a row or having a symmetrical character string. That would require counting.

Comment: @classstacker obviously this would require inf number of states which conflicts with finite automate

Comment: Yes, and it wouldn't be the fiist trick question in a textbook / exam. ;)

Comment: @classstacker I remember my exam on formal languages. Being best on the year wasn't enough to solve more than 2 out of 3 tasks :D It's wonderful science.

Comment: Agreed. Opening up a universe of insights, undervalued, and my major field of studies at that time. Still have the Aho / Sethi / Ullman on the shelf.